# iOS background audio stops when screen is locked

Tags: ios, audio, background, multitasking

I'm trying to get my audio app to play in the background. So far I added "app plays audio" to the "required background modes" in info.plist and also the following code just before starting my sound generator:

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, &interruptionListener, sgD);
AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, &routeChangeListener, sgD);

// select "Playback" audio session category
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];

OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback; 
propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty ( kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (category), &category );

AudioSessionSetActive(true);
```

However, this works only when I switch to another app or to the iPod's main screen. When I turn off the screen, it also turns off my audio output, which is definitely not what I want. However, all tutorials / documentation / answers to questions on stackoverflow seem to indicate that keeping the audio running while the screen is off comes automatically when you get the background audio to work. Does anybody have a hint for me? Thanks a lot in advance!
Fritz

Comment: What I forgot to say: I'm using AudioQueues to generate the audio output stream. The Audio Queue callback gets called while the screen is off, but not sound is heard at the headphones. This might indicate some audio route problem. However, my route change callback is never called.

Comment: Ok, problem solved... It turns out that the audio buffer size has to be big enough if it should run while the screen is turned off. I don't know if this applies to all apps, but my app needed a buffer size of at least 2048 samples. With 1024 samples it just stopped working.

Comment: If you were able to get it to work, could you add your solution as an answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Fritz, can you specify where you're setting the audio buffer size?  I'm running into the same problem and when I look at my Render Callback, the buffers are limited to 1024 samples.  But I don't see where I can increase this value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article explains the problem:

[Technical Q&A QA1606
Audio Unit Processing Graph - Ensuring audio playback continues when screen is locked](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1606/_index.html)

Basically, you just need to make sure you set all AudioUnits to support 4096 slices:

```
// set the mixer unit to handle 4096 samples per slice since we want to keep rendering during screen lock
UInt32 maxFPS = 4096;
AudioUnitSetProperty(
    mMixer,
    kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice,
    kAudioUnitScope_Global,
    0,
    &maxFPS,
    sizeof(maxFPS));
```

Comment: Any idea how to apply this to AVAudioEngine?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I'm having the same problem, and I couldn't find other related questions or answers.  No matter how I configured my AudioQueue callback, I couldn't get it to consistently go into the background without having audio dropouts.  If I made the buffers huge, then it was almost working consistently, but with giant buffers the audio response delay for the UI was excessively long.

The only solution I found that worked was to switch from AudioQueue to Audio Units (RemoteIO) for my callback, and unlike what is stated in the previous solution here, I didn't find that it was necessary to set the Audio Unit buffer size to 4096.  I still get a very small dropout when the app goes into the background if it's attached to the debugger, but when the app is running normally without the debugger then I don't get any dropouts.