# Audio Queue (with high sample rate) will suffer audio cap when lock the screen

Tags: ios, background, audio-streaming, multitasking

Guys:

Today, I was debugging my streaming internet radio app.

I use Audio Queue Service to playback the PCM buffer decoded from FFMPEG.

And in order to keep playback behavior while lock the screen, I did following two things:

1)Add UIBackGroundMode in info.plist

2)Use AVAudioSession to set "AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback"

After these operations, I run the app on my iPhone, and it did keep playing back sound when I press the screen-lock key to enter sleep mode

However, the sound turned to be shaky with significant audio cap.

I tested the audio streaming (in screen-locked mode) with different sample rate:

1)at 32000, the audio cap can be detected

2)at 37500, the audio caps are too heavy to tell the audio sound

3)at 41000, the audio is terminated completely

Does anybody known what is happen for this problem?

It seems iOS decrease its sample rate for processing audio queue data while it turn to screen-lock mode?

Should I configure some thing to keep the iPhone's sample rate when screen is locked?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem with the enlightenment from Fritz Menzer and his former question.

[iOS background audio stops when screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085007/ios-background-audio-stops-when-screen-is-locked?rq=1)

He answered his own question with an important summery:

"It turns out that the audio buffer size has to be big enough if it should run while the screen is turned off"

Therefore, I adjust my code by increasing the number of packets sent to Audio queue on each buffer handling cycle (1 originally, and I adjusted it to 16). See the code below:

```
    static OSStatus AqCreateAudioQueue(AQPlayerState *pAqData)
    {
        OSStatus result;
        bool isFormatVBR;

        result = AudioQueueNewOutput(&(pAqData->mDataFormat),
                                     HandleOutputBuffer,
                                     pAqData,
                                     CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                                     kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                                     0,
                                     &(pAqData->mQueue));

        pAqData->bufferByteSize = AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;
        //pAqData->mNumPacketsToRead = 1; 
        //one packet in each buffer-handling cycle is not enough
        pAqData->mNumPacketsToRead = PACKETS_TO_READ;
        //I defined PACKETS_TO_READ as 16

        ...
    }
```

After this adjustment, I ran my app again, it did work! the audio sound is stable without any audio gap when I locked the screen.

Thanks, Fritz Menzer!!