# iOS background audio gets stopped when playback is finished

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

There are couple of questions already on SOW,about [playing audio in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085007/ios-background-audio-stops-when-screen-is-locked), but mine is a little different(as far as I could see!)

So I've a playlist in my app, where user can choose to play an audio in a loop, or a random/continuous playback for all the audios available in the app.

Using below code, and the required Info.plist setting:

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];`

Info.plist setting:

`<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
    </array>`

The audio works properly in the background, and even when screen is locked, but the problem arises when the audio playback gets finished.
Using NSLogs, I can see that the code reaches again the AudioPlayer's "play" method, but the audio doesn't play the next song, or the song which was to be played in the loop.

Does anyone have pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), the relevant paragraph:

My audios are stored locally in the app.
When the UIBackgroundModes key contains the audio value, the system’s media frameworks automatically prevent the corresponding app from being suspended when it moves to the background. *As long as it is playing audio or video content or recording audio content, the app continues to run in the background.*

**However, if recording or playback stops, the system suspends the app.**

So essentially, to hack around the setup, I used two AVAudioPlayers, and instead of waiting for the delegate callback for audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:, I worked this out:

if ((audioPlayer1.duration - audioPlayer1.currentTime) < 1) {

```
 //play Audio 2
```

}

Not too sure if there's any better suggestion than this?